# Jenkins git plugin, how to trigger build only on certain tags?

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm looking to trigger builds in Jenkins only when the tag created has a certain format. My code is in Gitlab and the way it works now is like this.
When i create a tag on `master` branch the Jenkins plugin will trigger the job for 2 environments, `staging` and `prod`. I'm using `refs/tags/${TAGNAME}` as a parameter for Branch Specifier (blank for 'any') field inside the Jenkins job. The thing is sometimes i need to deploy code on `staging` but not release it to `prod` and i have to manually disable the prod jobs. I also use `TAGNAME` as a parameter to manually deploy a certain tag.

I tested with the possibility to use a regex and create tags for `staging` using this format `v1.0.0-rc` and for `prod` using this format `v1.0.0`. I created this regex `:^(?!.*(-rc)).*` but it won't trigger no matter what. Then i discovered that i need to include the `TAGNAME` variable but now the regex will always trigger because the variable contains the tag from Gitlab ex:`v1.0.0-rc`

If you want to test the regex you can use this examples:

```
refs/tags/v1.0.1
refs/tags/v1.0.1-rc
refs/tags/v1.0.1^{commit}
refs/remotes/origin/refs/tags/v1.0.1^{commit}
refs/remotes/origin/refs/tags/v1.0.1-rc^{commit}
v1.0.1
v1.0.1-rc
```

It should match only the lines whitout `-rc`.

But at this point i don't think it's the best approach. Is there a way i can do this triggering based on a certain tag naming?